# Convolution of Narayana polynomials

Tags: reference-request, convolution

I would like to find a reference for the following result:

Let $C_n(t)=\sum\limits_{k =  0}^{n-1} {\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{1}{n+1}t^k}$ for $n>0$ and $C_0(t)=1$ be Narayana  polynomials.
Then the $m-$fold convolution $C^{(m)}_n(t)$ is given by
$C^{(m)}_n(t)=\sum\limits_{k =  0}^{n-1} {\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n+m}{k+m}\frac{m}{n+m}t^k}$ for $n>0.$

**Edit**:
I In the mean time I have seen that this convolution identity follows rather trivially from the generating function  $C(t,z)=\sum{ C_n(t) z^n}$, which satisfies
$tzC(t,z)^2=C(t,z)-1-zC(t,z)+tzC(t,z)$.
It suffices to  multiply this identity with $C(t,z)^{m-2}$ and compare coefficients.

Nevertheless I would be interested if the above identity occurs in the literature.

Comment: It would seem this problem can be reduced to what appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498014/). I will post the modified computation soon if no additional answer has appeared by then.

Comment: @Felix Marin: Thank you, I have corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we define

$$C_0^{(1)}(t) = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad
C_n^{(1)}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} {n+1\choose k+1}
\frac{1}{n+1} t^k$$

and let for $m\ge 2$

$$C_n^{(m)}(t) = \sum_{q=0}^n C_q^{(m-1)}(t) C_{n-q}^{(1)}(t).$$

This definition is equivalent to introducing

$$G(w) = \sum_{n\ge 1} C_n^{(1)}(t) w^n$$ and letting

$$C_n^{(m)}(t) = [w^n] (1+G(w))^m
= [w^n] \sum_{p=0}^m {m\choose p} G(w)^p.$$

We seek to show that

$$C_0^{(m)}(t) = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad
C_n^{(m)}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} {n+m\choose k+m}
\frac{m}{n+m} t^k.$$

The proof  will consist  in doing  a coefficient  extraction operation
from the  powers of $G(w)$ and  showing that these match  the proposed
formula.  We require an alternate representation of $C_n^{(1)}(t)$ and
observe that

$${n-1\choose k} {n+1\choose k+1} \frac{1}{n+1}
= {n\choose k+1} \frac{k+1}{n} 
{n\choose k} \frac{n+1}{k+1} \frac{1}{n+1}
\\ = \frac{1}{n} {n\choose k+1} {n\choose k}.$$

and introduce

$${n\choose k+1} = {n\choose n-k-1} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^{n-k}} (1+z)^{n} \; dz$$

which conveniently vanishes for $k\ge n.$ We get for $n\ge 1$

$$C_n^{(1)}(t) =
\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^{n}} (1+z)^{n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {n\choose k} z^k t^k
 \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^{n}} (1+z)^{n}
(1+tz)^{n}
 \; dz.$$

We re-write this as

$$\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^{n}}
(1+z(1+t+tz))^{n}
\; dz.$$

Extracting the coefficient yields

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q}
[z^{n-1-q}] (1+t+tz)^{q}
\\ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q}
{q\choose n-1-q} (1+t)^{q-(n-1-q)} t^{n-1-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q}
{q\choose n-1-q} (1+t)^{2q+1-n} t^{n-1-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose n-1-q}
{n-1-q\choose q} (1+t)^{n-1-2q} t^{q}.$$

Now we have

$$\frac{1}{n} {n\choose n-1-q}{n-1-q\choose q} =
\frac{1}{n} \frac{n!}{(q+1)! q! (n-1-2q)!} \\ =
\frac{1}{n} {2q+1\choose q} {n\choose 2q+1}
= \frac{1}{2q+1} {2q+1\choose q} {n-1\choose 2q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2q+1} {2q+1\choose q+1} {n-1\choose 2q}
= \frac{1}{q+1} {2q\choose q} {n-1\choose 2q}$$

where $$C_q = \frac{1}{q+1} {2q\choose q}$$

is a Catalan number. We thus obtain for $G(w)$

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} w^n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} C_q {n-1\choose 2q}
(1+t)^{n-1-2q} t^q
\\ = w \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n \sum_{q=0}^{n} C_q {n\choose 2q}
(1+t)^{n-2q} t^q
\\ = w \sum_{q\ge 0} C_q (1+t)^{-2q} t^q
\sum_{n\ge q} {n\choose 2q} w^n (1+t)^n
\\ = w \sum_{q\ge 0} C_q (1+t)^{-2q} t^q
\sum_{n\ge 2q} {n\choose 2q} w^n (1+t)^n
\\ = w \sum_{q\ge 0} C_q (1+t)^{-2q} t^q w^{2q} (1+t)^{2q}
\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+2q\choose 2q} w^n (1+t)^n
\\ = w \sum_{q\ge 0} C_q  t^q w^{2q} 
\frac{1}{(1-w(1+t))^{2q+1}}
\\ = \frac{w}{(1-w(1+t))} \sum_{q\ge 0} C_q  t^q w^{2q} 
\frac{1}{(1-w(1+t))^{2q}}.$$

Now the classic generating function of the Catalan numbers is

$$Q(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}.$$

We have computed the closed form of $G(w)$ which is

$$G(w) = \frac{w}{(1-w(1+t))}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4tw^2/(1-w(1+t))^2}}{2tw^2/(1-w(1+t))^2}
\\ = w \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4tw^2/(1-w(1+t))^2}}{2tw^2/(1-w(1+t))}
\\ = w \frac{1-w(1+t)-\sqrt{(1-w(1+t))^2-4tw^2}}{2tw^2}
\\ = \frac{1-w(1+t)-\sqrt{(1-w(1+t))^2-4tw^2}}{2tw}.$$

Recall the functional equation of the Catalan number generating function which is

$$Q(x) = 1 + x Q(x)^2.$$

We thus obtain

$$Q\left(\frac{tw^2}{(1-w(1+t))^2}\right)
= 1 + \frac{tw^2}{(1-w(1+t))^2} Q\left(\frac{tw^2}{(1-w(1+t))^2}\right)^2$$

or

$$\frac{1-w(1+t)}{w} G(w) = 1 + t G(w)^2.$$

Solving for $w$ we get

$$G(w) -  w(1+t) G(w) = w(1+tG(w)^2)$$

or $$G(w) = w(1+(1+t)G(w)+tG(w)^2)$$

which is

$$w = \frac{G(w)}{1+(1+t)G(w)+tG(w)^2}.$$

Recall that we seek 
$$[t^k] \sum_{p=0}^m {m\choose p} [w^n] G(w)^p.$$

We establish the coefficient extraction integral (Lagrange inversion)

$$[w^n] G(w)^p 
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} G(w)^p \; dw.$$

Setting $v=G(w)$ and observing that $w=0$ is mapped to $v=0$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+(1+t)v+tv^2)^{n+1}}{v^{n+1}}
\\ \times v^p \times
\left(\frac{1}{1+(1+t)v+tv^2} - \frac{v(1+t+2tv)}{(1+(1+t)v+tv^2)^2}\right)
\; dv.$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+(1+t)v+tv^2)^{n-1}}{v^{n-p+1}}
(1+(1+t)v+tv^2-v(1+t+2tv)) \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+v)^{n-1} (1+tv)^{n-1}}{v^{n-p+1}}
(1-tv^2)  \; dv.$$

Now substituting this into the target formula yields

$$C_n^{(m)}(t) = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+v)^{n-1} (1+tv)^{n-1}}{v^{n+1}}
(1-tv^2) \sum_{p=0}^m {m\choose p} v^p  \; dv
\\ =  \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+v)^{n+m-1} (1+tv)^{n-1}}{v^{n+1}}
(1-tv^2)\; dv.$$

To  conclude the  proof  we must  treat  the case  of  $n=0$ which  is
different from the  case $n\ge 1$ and extract  coefficients on $[t^k]$
in the latter case. With $n=0$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} (1+v)^{m-1} \frac{1}{v} \frac{1}{1+tv}
(1-tv^2)\; dv.$$

This is the constant coefficient and is equal to

$$\left.(1+v)^{m-1} \frac{1}{1+tv}
(1-tv^2)\right|_{v=0} = 1,$$

as required. For the case of $n\ge  1$ we have two subcases, $k=0$ and
$k\ge 1.$  For $k=0$ the second  term in $1-tv^2$ does  not contribute
and we have just

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+v)^{n+m-1}}{v^{n+1}} \; dv
\\ = {n+m-1\choose n} = {n+m-1\choose m-1}
= {n+m\choose m} \frac{m}{n+m}.$$

This is again  the required value. Finally when $n\ge  1$ and $k\ge 1$
we get two pieces, namely

$${n-1\choose k}\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+v)^{n+m-1}}{v^{n-k+1}} \; dv 
= {n-1\choose k} {n+m-1\choose n-k}$$

and

$$-{n-1\choose k-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{(1+v)^{n+m-1}}{v^{n-k}} \; dv
= -{n-1\choose k-1} {n+m-1\choose n-k-1}.$$

Note that when $k=n$ the first of these integrals never appears in the
first place because  $[t^k] (1+tv)^{n-1} = 0$ and  the second vanishes
due to the residue. When $k\gt n$ we have $[t^k] (1+tv)^{n-1} (1-tv^2)
= 0$ and everything vanishes.  This  is the required behavior.  We get
for the non-zero cases

$${n-1\choose k} {n+m-1\choose k+m-1}
- {n-1\choose k-1} {n+m-1\choose k+m}
\\ = {n-1\choose k} {n+m\choose k+m} \frac{k+m}{n+m}
- {n-1\choose k} \frac{k}{n-k} {n+m\choose k+m} \frac{n-k}{n+m}
\\ = {n-1\choose k} {n+m\choose k+m} \frac{m}{n+m}.$$

We  have the  required  value as  was  to  be shown  and  may end  the
computation.

Comment: This is an interesting tour de force!

You  first derive the (known) closed formula for the generating function $G(t,z)=\sum\limits_{j \ge 0}{ C_{n+1}(t) z^{n+1}}$ in place of $C(t,z)$
and then you use Lagrange’ formula to obtain the desired result.