# Inequality of Narayana numbers

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

In some computations I am making, it is desirable to deduce that a certain expression is positive. I managed to rewrite it in terms of Narayana numbers, which are defined by $N(n,i) := \frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i-1}$.

> Prove that for every $n$ and $\ell$ and every $1\leq a \leq n-1$, the following inequality holds
> $$ \sum_{i=0}^{\ell} N(a,i+1) N(n-a, \ell-i+1) \leq N(n,\ell+1)$$

I tried to look for some identities that these Narayana numbers satisfy, but the amount of information that pops out turns to be a bit overwhelming. Any simplification or indication of how to proceed would be highly appreciated. I should mention that I found the following question [An Identity Involving Narayana Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498014/an-identity-involving-narayana-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1) inspiring, though it seems it is not easy to use it directly in this problem.

Comment: I can only prove that $\sum_{i=0}^\ell N(a, i+1)N(n-a,\ell-i+1)\le N(n,\color{red}{\ell+2})$.

Comment: Dear Mike, I figured out an idea that I think that kills easily the inequality you wrote in your comment, and also the one that I posted above. Essentially, it amounts to using that the Narayana number $N(n,m)$ counts the number of paths between $(0,0)$ and $(2n,0)$ using NW or SW steps and do not go below the $x$-axis, and that have exactly $m$ peaks. The injection to show your inequality is direct, and for mine is tricky but seemingly doable (if I did not make any mistake).

Comment: I would be curious to see what you came up with. If you post an answer, I can double-check your work. You and I are thinking the same way to prove the $N(n,\ell+2)$ inequality, in terms of Dyck paths and counting peaks.

Comment: I am down to check also this. I see clearly the inequality mentioned by Mike, but not at all the original one.